# How to add a struct column to a spark dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, struct, apache-spark-sql

I have this dataframe:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

Example data:

```
+------+------+
| Id   | Name |
+------+------+
|  1   |  'A' |
+------+------+
|  2   |  'B' |
+------+------+
```

I would like to add a Items column which is a nested struct with data like this:

```
{Id:{"Id":Id,"Name":Name}}
```

The final schema should look like this:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 1: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 2: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

The final data should look like this:

```
+------+------+-----------------------------+
| Id   | Name | Items                       |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  1   |  'A' |  {1:{"Id":1, "Name": "A"}}  |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
|  2   |  'B' |  {2:{"Id":2, "Name": "B"}}  |
+------+------+-----------------------------+
```

I tried this expr:

```
transform_expr_items = """struct(Id, struct(Id as Id,
                                      Name as Name
                                ))"""

df_tmp = df_test.withColumn("Items", expr(transform_expr_items))
```

But got a schema look like this:

```
root
 |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Items: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- col2: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- Id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- Name: string (nullable = true)
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can try defining the schema beforehand and utilizing that over the data that is getting parsed as follows:

```py
# Create a DataFrame
data = [("1", "A"), ("2", "B")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ["Id", "Name"])

# Add a new Items Column (Items=Map[Id,Name])
df = df.withColumn("Items", F.create_map(F.col("Id"), F.struct(F.col("Id"), F.col("Name"))))

# Define the schema beforehand, then apply to data that is read
new_schema = StructType([
    StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Name", StringType(), True),
    StructField("Items", StructType([
        StructField("1", StructType([
            StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Name", StringType(), True)
        ]), True),
        StructField("2", StructType([
            StructField("Id", StringType(), True),
            StructField("Name", StringType(), True)
        ]), True)
    ]), True)
])

# Apply the new schema, display the transformed data & schema
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(df.rdd, new_schema)
df_new.show(df_new.count(), False)
df_new.printSchema()
```

Comment: Thanks. Even though this creates map type of fileds in the df, the generated json file has the correct format. So I would like to accept this as the answer.